# Grid search for estimation of degrees of freedom parameters in likelihood function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, copula, profile-likelihood

In the script below I attempt to estimate parameters for Apple and Amazon using a Gaussian Copula with t-Student marginals for the purpose of this exercice.
When executing the script, I notice at each iteration that the estimate of nu1 and nu2 seem to be problematic and in the output I seem to be getting good estimates of mu1 and mu2 however the five other parameters (sd1, sd2, nu1, nu2, and theta) are all at their upper bound. So I suspect that I would need to implement a grid search in order estimate nu1 and nu2 properly, however I am totally stumped as to how to implement this estimation method in my current script.
Any help would be appreciated.
**I know I could be employing simple commands with special packages that would easily fit the model, however I'd rather try to estimate the model using the likelihood function.

```
#install.packages("tseries")
library('tseries')
#install.packages("copula")
library('copula')
x1 <- get.hist.quote(instrument = "aapl", start = "2002-01-01", end = "2010-01-01", quote = "Close") 

ret1 <- 100*diff(log(as.numeric(x1$Close)))


x2 <- get.hist.quote(instrument = "amzn", start = "2002-01-01", end = "2010-01-01", quote = "Close") 

ret2 <- 100*diff(log(as.numeric(x2$Close)))

X <- cbind(ret1, ret2)

Ut <- cbind(pt(X[,1], df=3),pt(X[,2], df=3.5))
Ut <- pmax(pmin(Ut, 1 - 1e-7), 1e-7)

Xmeta1 <- cbind(qt(Ut[,1], df=3),qt(Ut[,2], df=3.5))

like <- function(pars){
  
  mu1   <- pars[1]
  sd1  <- pars[2]
  nu1  <- pars[3]
  mu2   <- pars[4]
  sd2  <- pars[5]
  nu2  <- pars[6]
  theta <- pars[7]
  
  llike <- matrix(0,length(ret1),1)
  clike <- matrix(0,length(ret1),1)
  llike1 <- matrix(0,length(ret1),1)
  llike2 <- matrix(0,length(ret1),1)      
  
  temp <- normalCopula(param = theta) 
  
  for (t in 1:length(ret1)){
    llike1[t] <- dt((ret1[t]-mu1)/sd1, df=nu1, log=TRUE)
    llike2[t] <- dt((ret2[t]-mu2)/sd2, df=nu2, log=TRUE)    
    u1 <- pt((ret1[t]-mu1)/sd1, df=nu1)
    u2 <- pt((ret2[t]-mu2)/sd2, df=nu2) 
    u1 <- pmax(pmin(u1, 1 - 1e-7), 1e-7)
    u2 <- pmax(pmin(u2, 1 - 1e-7), 1e-7)
    clike[t] <- log( dCopula(c(u1,u2),temp) )
    llike[t] <- clike[t] + llike1[t] + llike2[t]
  }
  ans <- sum(llike)
  print(c(pars,ans))
  return(ans)
}

Y1 <- Xmeta1[,1]
Y2 <- Xmeta1[,2]

pars0 <- c(mean(Y1),sd(Y1),3,mean(Y2),sd(Y2),3.5,cor(Y1,Y2)) 

temp <- optim(pars0,like,method="L-BFGS-B",control=list(fnscale=-1),lower=c(-1,0.1,2,-1,0.1,2,-0.98),upper=c(1,10,15,1,10,15,0.98),hessian=TRUE) # You need to include 'df' in your bounds

pars1 <- temp$par

Ihat <- -1 * temp$hessian
SE <- sqrt(diag(solve(Ihat)))

print(pars1)
```

Comment: Are you sure about your calculation of the log likelihood?  (I don't see some essential terms arising from the Jacobians.)  It would be best to see it expressed mathematically rather than in code so that everyone can read and understand it.